# How to refresh a token for Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm connecting to the Microsoft Graph using:

```
public GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient(string token)
{
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                // Append the access token to the request.
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
            }));
    return graphClient;
}
```

I'm running this code on the server. The token I'm using is being sent to me by an external App.

Everything works great during the first hour, then the token expires.

**My question is** : How can I get a new token, since I also have access to the refresh token?

Comment: Can you show how you are getting your access token?

Comment: @MichaelMainer Sure ! https://pastebin.com/ix3cm7sL

Comment: Would you also share the part where you get the refresh-token?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two pieces required to enable Refresh Tokens:

1. You need to request the scope `offline_access`. This tells the endpoint to provide a `refresh_token` alongside the `access_token` and associated metadata.
2. You need to request a new `access_token` (and `refresh_token` as they come together) by repeating the same `POST` to `/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` with a slightly different body - `grant_type` is set to `refresh_token` and instead of a `code`, you supply a `refresh_token` property and value:

   ```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   grant_type=refresh_token&
   refresh_token=[REFRESH TOKEN]&
   client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&
   client_secret=[PASSWORD]&
   scope=[SCOPE]&
   redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]
   ```

A while back I wrote up a show [primer on the v2 Endpoint](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) that you might find helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that. It's a pity that we don't have a method for that on the Microsoft.Graph Library. Still I will do the http request like you say. The redirect_uri  does not make that much sense since I will be doing the call from the backend, although I assume I need to send the same value I had previously defined on the Microsoft Developer console.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to some c# code showing how to get a refresh-token or is this possible only by calling the API manually with an http-client?

Comment: Everytime this request returns new refresh token. Do these refresh tokens have fresh 90 day lifetime ? Or I will have to relogin anyway after 90 days?

Comment: Each refresh of the auth token also generates a new refresh token. The new refresh token will expire 90 days from the time it was generated.

Answer (score 6):

This helped me, when i was not having refreshToken
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

```
POST /oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1 Host: login.microsoftonline.com 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer  
&client_id=2846f71b-a7a4-4987-bab3-760f389 
&client_secret=BYyVnAt56JpLwUcyo47XODd 
&assertion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIs...pa970UvdVfQ 
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read+offline_access 
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
```

sample response:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "User.Read Mail.Read Mail.Send Calendars.Read",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "EwCAA8l6BAAUO9chh8cJscQLmU+LSWpbnr0v...ZgNcrJkgI=",
    "refresh_token": "MCS3KUzqyCY6rQH*NXLSLQctqj47w...x3Oa4r"
}
```

Comment: The main point here is adding `offline_access` to the scope (after a space).

Answer (score 1):

below shell-scirpt worked for me for renewing access_token using refresh_token of MS-Graph/Azure-AD

```
# SCRIPT BEGINS FROM HERE #
echo "SCRIPT EXECUTION BEGINS"
echo " "
echo "Script to  request new access token and refresh token from refresh token of MS-Graph apis"
echo " "
echo "You can also follow this links for reference" 
echo "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTULjLL-ZDI"   
echo "https://dzone.com/articles/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oau-1" 
echo " "
echo "If don't know your Azure-AD-Tenant-Name then just follow this below link to get it"
echo "https://helpdesk.kaseya.com/hc/en-gb/articles/115002521251-How-Do-I-Find-My-Azure-AD-Tenant-Name-"
echo " "
read -p "Enter your Tenant name : " tenant
echo "Tenant named your entered is: $tenant "

echo " "
read -p "Enter your client_id: " client_id
echo "Client_id you entered is: $client_id"

echo " "
read -p "Enter your client_secret: " client_secret
echo "Client_secret you entered is: $client_secret"

echo " "
read -p "Enter your redirect_uri (eg. http://localhost): " redirect_uri
echo "redirect_uri you entered is: $redirect_uri"

echo " "
echo "Enter the refresh_token value you haved copied from postman"
read -p "Enter your refresh token: " refresh_token
echo " "
echo "Refresh_token: " $refresh_token


authorization_endpoint=$(curl -s  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" | jq -r '.authorization_endpoint')
token_endpoint=$(curl -s  "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" | jq -r '.token_endpoint')

echo " "
echo "Authorize endpoint of your tenant is"
echo "$authorization_endpoint"

echo " "
echo "Token endpoint of your tenant is"

echo "$token_endpoint"


#token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"   --data-urlencode 'client_id=63bf591a-e1c' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=WUR-AH-7ML1fSHT_oH6HVVA8Jd' --data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost'  --data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token' --data-urlencode 'refresh_token=$refresh_token' --data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' --data-urlencode 'tenant=$tenant' )

#token=$(curl -s -X POST "$token_endpoint" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data-urlencode "client_id=45789-87a3-cbb1d1076b3b" --data-urlencode "client_secret=_oH6HVVA8Jd5p9OCa-S" --data-urlencode "redirect_uri=http://localhost" --data-urlencode "grant_type=refresh_token" --data-urlencode "refresh_token=$refresh_token" --data-urlencode "scope=openid profile offline_access  https://graph.microsoft.com" --data-urlencode "tenant=$tenant" | jq .access_token)

token=$(curl -s -X POST "$token_endpoint" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data-urlencode "client_id=$client_id" --data-urlencode "client_secret=$client_secret" --data-urlencode "redirect_uri=$redirect_uri" --data-urlencode "grant_type=refresh_token" --data-urlencode "refresh_token=$refresh_token" --data-urlencode "scope=openid profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" --data-urlencode "tenant=$tenant" | jq .access_token)
echo " "
echo "Your renewed access token is:"
echo " "
echo "$token"
echo " "
echo "SCRIPT ENDS"

# SCRIPT ENDS HERE
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a way to do this, but it is only recommended for ADAL.NET 2.x to MSAL.NET 2.x migration scenarios, which is outlined here:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal

Only for client credentials (not auth code).