# How to get microsoft graph refresh token java sdk?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

How can I get a Microsoft graph refresh token using java SDK?
I am using java SDK of graph and got the access token. How can I get a refresh token in java SDK using this accessToken?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh a token for Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153055/how-to-refresh-a-token-for-microsoft-graph)

Comment: No.
I am using Java SDK. Let's say i have got a graphClient initialized using the access token. Now the token will surely expire after 59 minutes.According to this initialized graphclient should stop working. How can I get the refresh token or update graphclient in Java SDK

Comment: Or is it like if "once graphclient is initialized using access token you can use it as long as you want without any need to re-initialize it."

Comment: answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51161027/12396017 describes the use of grant type REFRESH TOKEN and SDK contains method which does such thing -  com.microsoft.graph.auth.BaseAuthentication -> getAccessTokenSilent() -> setGrantType(GrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN) - I vote to close this question as an duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Client credential flow, you don't get the refresh token. You can simply request a new access token again. A better idea will be to use https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth for auto-refresh of access token which will save you a lot of programming efforts